# How to divide a larger number by a subset of smaller numbers with no remainder

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a set of spacers that must fill a gap of a certain size. The gap must be completely filled with no space left over. The gap has to be filled by the least amount of spacers. The spacers are limited in quantity.

```
    const SPACERS = [
      .05,
      .0505,
      .051,
      .052,
      .054,
      .058,
      .06,
      .07,
      .08,
      .09,
      .1,
      .2,
      .4,
      .8,
      1.6,
      3.2
    ]
    const SPACERQTY = {
      "0.05": 52,
      "0.0505" : 8,
      "0.051" : 40,
      "0.052" : 40,
      "0.054" : 40,
      "0.058" : 40,
      "0.06" : 36,
      "0.07" : 36,
      "0.08" : 36,
      "0.09" : 36,
      "0.1" : 48,
      "0.2" : 16,
      "0.4" : 16,
      "0.8" : 16,
      "1.6" : 8,
      "3.2" : 8,
    }
```

The function below is taking a `stripWdith` of `20.998`.

```
function getSpacersBetweenKnives(stripWidth) {
  let spacersNeeded = []
  SPACERS.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
  for(v=0;v<SPACERS.length;v++) {
    let spacersRemaining = SPACERQTY[SPACERS[v].toString()]
    if(stripWidth <= 0) {
      break
    }
    while(spacersRemaining > 0) {
      if(stripWidth - SPACERS[v] >= 0) {
        spacersNeeded.push(SPACERS[v])
        stripWidth = (stripWidth-SPACERS[v]).toFixed(4)
        spacersRemaining--
        if(stripWidth <= 0) {
          break
        }
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
  }
  return spacersNeeded
}
```

The issue I am having is I am left over with a gap of `.008`.
Here is my output:

```
[
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
1.6,
0.1,
0.09
]
```

The actual output should look like this:

```
[
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
3.2,
.8,
.009,
.058,
.05
]
```

The part I am struggling with is how to determine to use a smaller spacer even though I have larger ones available. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question looks well written with an actual result and desired result. However it's still not 100% clear what you are trying to do. Can you edit your question to explain your actual task a bit more clearder? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to solve is called [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), but with arbitrary denominations you can't rely on a greedy algorithm. Also you need to use integer values, because otherwise the calculation can break due to floating point rounding errors (in your case it should be sufficient to pre-multiply `SPACERS` and `stripWidth` by a factor of 10000).

Comment: @blakkwater I greatly appreciate the link as well as the heads up on the floating point errors. The change-making problem looks to be the solution. Once I implement it and confirm, I will mark the question answered.